# wordpress ajax request doesn't reach the backend function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

i have bad request 400 and this ajax object localization code in functions.php:

```
get_template_part('inc/ajax_functions');
function enqueue_theme_assets(){
wp_enqueue_script('ajax_functions', WDD_JS . 'ajax_functions.js', [] , filemtime(WDD_JS_PATH . 'ajax_functions.js'));
    wp_localize_script('ajax_functions', 'WDD_ajax_object', [
        'WDD_ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
        'WDD_ajax_nonce' => wp_create_nonce('WDD_ajax_nonce')
    ]
    );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_theme_assets');
```

this is the javascrit function in ajax_functions.js:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

  const data = {
    action: 'get_branches',
    security: WDD_ajax_object.WDD_ajax_nonce
  };
  console.log(WDD_ajax_object.WDD_ajax_url);
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: WDD_ajax_object.WDD_ajax_url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function (response) {
      if (response.success === false) {
        console.log('Request failed.' + response.data.error);
      } else {
        console.log(response.data);
      }
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
    }
  });


});
```

this is the php function in inc/ajax_functions.php:

```
function get_branches_callback()
    {
    if (!check_ajax_referer('WDD_ajax_nonce', 'security', false)) {
        wp_send_json_error(array('error' => 'Invalid security token.'));
        }

    
    die();

    }


add_action('wp_ajax_get_branches', 'get_branches_callback');
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_get_branches_callback', 'get_branches_callback' );
```

here is the console log for data object in ajax request:

```
{action: 'get_branches', security: 'eefbd1e431'}
```

so the the ajax object has been created and the ajax handler function exist in global $wp_filter,
but the call never reach the function can anyone help me with this

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in using an incorrect action name for non-private users. Here is a corrected example:

```
function get_branches_callback() {
    if ( ! check_ajax_referer( 'WDD_ajax_nonce', 'security', false ) ) {
        wp_send_json_error( array( 'error' => 'Invalid security token.' ) );
    }
    wp_send_json_success( array( 'message' => 'Everything is ok' ));
    wp_die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_branches', 'get_branches_callback' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_get_branches', 'get_branches_callback' );
```

The second problem is sending data incorrectly. Here is the correct way to solve it:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append('action', 'get_branches');
    data.append('security', WDD_ajax_object.WDD_ajax_nonce);
    console.log(WDD_ajax_object.WDD_ajax_url);
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: WDD_ajax_object.WDD_ajax_url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.success === false) {
                console.log('Request failed.' + response.data.error);
            } else {
                console.log(response.data);
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: it was a typo i have corrected it and no thing changes still code 400 bad request

Comment: Yes, I found the second error. You can see the solution above. In short, you need to use `new FormData()` to create the form data. The object 'data' can be used with the `jQuery.post()` method.